# S.M.A.R.T Statues Bad

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, freeze, hardware-failure

There are some similar questions already but I think this is different.

I have a X554L Asus notebook with Windows 10 on it. When I push the power on button, after Asus logo, I see a black screen, black screen with a blinking "_", freezed windows logo without rotating dots, windows logo with "Diagnosing Your PC" or "Recovering Your PC" under (sometimes freezed), or one of the following messages:

> Reboot and Select proper Boot device
> or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key_

> A disk read error occurred
> Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart

> Port O : HGST HTE721010A9E630
> S.M.A.R.T Statues Bad. Backup and Replace
> Press F1 to resume

Today after the "windows logo with Recovering Your PC" I got the following:

> Recovery
> Your PC couldn't start properly
> An unexpected I/O error has occurred.
> Error code : 0xc00000e9
> This problem happens when a removable storage device is removed while it's in use or is failing. Properly connecting any
> removable storage and restarting you PC may fix this problem
>
> Press Enter to try again
> Press F8 for startup setting

My computer freezes very often but will often work after a few minutes. Some times I get "UNEXPECTED_STORE_EXCEPTION" blue screen and sometimes there are strange sounds when the blue screen happens.

I used to see the messages "Reboot and ..." and "A disk error ...". With a computer engineer's opinion I bought another hard drive but no success. Before I changed my hard drive, when the computer freezed there was no chance that it would work so I always shut it down. Before I changed my hard drive I run the command `chkdsk` and it said "There are some issues but we can't fix it" but when I run the command now everything is fine. My guess is that the guy changed my hard drive made a mistake, like not attaching the cables correctly.

I'm not sure about this but I think shaking the computer a little while booting helps.

The question is "What is the issue and how can I fix it?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Port O : HGST HTE721010A9E630 S.M.A.R.T Statues Bad. Backup and
> Replace Press F1 to resume

Your hard drive is failing and you have limited time to back everything up to a USB drive.

Once that is done, only you can decide whether to replace the drive (reasonably economical), or whether now is time for a new computer.

But be sure to back up before it is too late to get your data.

Comment: There is no physical guarantee on how long a drive can last.  The S.M.A.R.T. errors do say drive issues. If computer hardware is causing issues (unusual) it may be time to replace

Comment: Thanks. Just one other question: Can the computer harm HDD? I don't think it happens accidentally.

Comment: I don't think so, but your drive is failing and it is not clear what is causing the damage

Comment: Note that mechanical components like spinning HDDs and Fans have the shortest lifespan of any computer component (assuming the system is getting clean power), so think of it like every second they are alive, they are spinning themselves to death. Note that that specific model of disks started production in 2014, and models don't get produced for long, so I'm guessing it is already quite old.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely that your technician made a mistake when connecting up the drive.  (There are only 2 cables of different sizes, and each can only go into the computer 1 way and they are not interchangable.  I can conceive of no way a drive can be plugged in incorrectly)

As @John has said, your drive is claiming its failing, and the way it is failing is consistent with the errors you are seeing, and the "need to repair" the drive.  You want to back up the disk ASAP and not rely on it.

If your technician was remiss it may have been in recommending a hard drive over an SSD.  (ssd's are a lot faster and more reliable - but are more expensive, and can be a drop-in replacement for your existing drive)

S.M.A.R.T provides information about what the drive thinks of itself, and it is used to make educated guesses as to if the drive is failing - which it is here.   You can install software that can read the raw S.M.A.R.T data ([CrystalDisk](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/) Info can do this) and this can tell you the information its using to determine why its failing.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any idea why my hard drives keep failing? (in fact I'm not sure if my first drive crashed. I think it was bad sector but I don't think these two are accidental)

Comment: It depends on quality. Good quality drives may (only may) last longer than consumer drives. I have a nasty suspicion that R&D dollars are going to improve SSD drives as HDD drives are seeing much reduced frequency in consumer and business computers.

Comment: @fathollahi It IS likely coincidetal - hard drives have huge variability in lifespans. Assuming a 5% per year failure rate in 1 year (see https://www.prosofteng.com/blog/how-long-do-hard-drives-last/) , there is a 1 in 20 chance the drive would fail fairly quickly.   If you are looking for external factors, computer vibration/lack of damping may affect the longevity of a drive, the way it was handled in transport, turning on/off the drive, temperature all play  a part.  We need S.M.A.R.T data to tell why its failing (but this wont help solve the problem). An SSD doesnt suffer these issues.

Comment: I always buy HDDs with 5-year warranties (though I agree with the others, you are best served having an SSD). that is generally a good indication that the disk is one of the better models that the company offers, and occasional lemons aside, that that disk was designed to last at least that period of time. Laptop HDDs generally have short lifespans than a comparable desktop disk, in part due to all the reasons DavidGo enumerated.